# How do I fix my top navigation bar to the bottom of my page in Wordpress template Bridge

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to move my navigation bar so it is fixed at the bottom of the page in a wordpress theme call Bridge. The URL is ipl.cotomo.co

Answer (score 0):

First, This is not Wordpress question. This is CSS question.
In your stylesheet.min.css "header.fixed,header.fixed_hiding" has "top:0px". You change it "bottom:0px"